# How to write variables into text file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have written a code to draw a user input image on canvas. After that i am extracting the pixel values of the location being clicked on and am trying to write them into a text file using ajax. However my onclick and ajax functions are not working. please tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEvent('load', function() {
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            c.width = img.width;
            c.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
  }
});  
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

canvas.onclick = function(e){
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = e.x;
var y = e.y;
var ccolor = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
var r = ccolor.data[0];
var g = ccolor.data[1];
var b = ccolor.data[2];
document.getElementById('imageLoader').value = r + ',' + g + ',' + b;
var rgb = document.getElementById('imageLoader').value;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax.txt',
    data: rgb,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="background:#ffffff; width:100%; padding:20px; ">
<label>Image File:</label><br/>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</div>

<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `url: 'ajax.txt'` it seems that you're trying to write to a text file using `ajax` which is not possible, you will have to create a server side component that can handle `POST` requests to do the file writing.

Comment: and is my canvas.onclick function correct?

Comment: thankyou, i will try to setup the server component in flask

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method executes an asynchronous HTTP request. You must setup your server to handle this request.

If you are trying to persist some client side data, you can, for instance, [set a cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), or use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors like, it should be `ccolor[n]` instead of `ccolor.data[n]`, `window.addEventListener(...)` instead of `window.addEvent(...)`. Also, you'll have to include all the code in the `"load"` listener function and `document.getElementById('imageLoader').value = r + ',' + g + ',' + b;` won't work because `imageLoader` is an `input` type `file` element.

Like I've said in my comment, you can't create/write to files using `ajax` you need a server side component that can handle HTTP requests in order to do that.

Here is a working version of you're code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            c.width = img.width;
            c.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
  }

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

canvas.onclick = function(e){
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = e.x;
var y = e.y;
var ccolor = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
var r = ccolor[0];
var g = ccolor[1];
var b = ccolor[2];
var rgb =  r + ',' + g + ',' + b;
console.log(rgb);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'serverSideComponent',
    data: rgb,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
});  
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="background:#ffffff; width:100%; padding:20px; ">
<label>Image File:</label><br/>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</div>

<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the rgb value is still not visible on console on clicking

Comment: @AishwaryaBhave I've just run this on my system and it works, the only thing I've did differently was to exclude this script `http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js` and include the JQuery library (is needed for the ajax call).

Comment: actually it's working however in the console it's showing context.getImageData  is not a finite floating point value

Comment: @AishwaryaBhave You've probably clicked the `canvas` before the image was fully loaded.

Comment: @AishwaryaBhave This error can also occur if you pass invalid values to the `getImageData(x,y,1,1)` method. Make sure `x` and `y` are valid numerical values.

Comment: yep that was the problem